# create a python dictionary where the value is a list of strings

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file in which there are 2 names on each line.
Let's say i have the following input:

name1 name2 
name3 name4 
name1 name5

I want to make a dictionary like this:

name1 : [name2, name5] 
name2 : name1 
name3 : name4 
name4 : name3 
name5 : name1

Here is the code I made but i can't figure out what i did wrong..

```
d = {} 
for i in range(len(l)): # consider l the input
    d[l[i]] = ""

for i in range(0, len(l), 2):
    e1 = l[i]
    e2 = l[i+1]

    d.update({e1 : [d[e1], e2]}) #i think the update operation is wrong here..
    d.update({e2 : [d[e2], e1]})
```

Comment: Can you add the output (e.g.: print(d)) of your program to make it easier to understand whats going wrong?

Comment: ... also `print(l)` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the two critical lines to:

```
d.setdefault(e1, []).append(e2)
d.setdefault(e2, []).append(e1)
```

This will start an empty list if the key is not present and then fill it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a defaultdict `d` which sets empty lists as the initial values for every key and populate them as you iterate over `l`.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
l = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name1', 'name5'] # Values come in pairs
d = defaultdict(list) # Defaults all keys to []

for i in range(0, len(l), 2):
    d[l[i]].append(l[i+1])
    d[l[i+1]].append(l[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use defaultdict:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict

>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i in range(0, len(l), 2):
...     d[e1].append(e2)
```